# How to access body of payload for a camel-cxf endpoint

Tags: soap, cxf

I have my CXF based Jax-WS webservice and trying to read Payload of request. 
I have org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint whose Dataformat I am setting to Payload.

I am making call to this Service with POST method with body as Soap envelope as follows.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/terminal_location/v2_0/local">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:getLocation>
         <loc:address>tel:+948420161525</loc:address>
         <loc:requestedAccuracy>500</loc:requestedAccuracy>
         <loc:acceptableAccuracy>500</loc:acceptableAccuracy>
      </loc:getLocation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here body is representation of GetLocation object of ParlayX protocol.

In my class, I receive CxfPayload object. I want to retrieve address and requestedAccuracy from the Payload body.
I tried to extract required data from getBodySources() and getBody() methods of CxfPayload. But could not succeed. I don't see the required data in the object.

I referred some examples from [link](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-HowtogetandsetSOAPheadersinPAYLOADmode) but could not succeed too.

Any idea how I can extract body data of payload ?

Comment: Could you also share your camel endpoint definition? Why do you need to extract from xml body? Instead you can parse your whole body to an object and jaxb through camel jaxb component. Also there is an alternative way that you can extract these data using xpath. If you clear your goal, I can help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. For example you can unmarshal it into a POJO and access it using Java methods. Or if you just want a few values from the payload, you can simply use XPath:

```
<setHeader headerName="address">
  <xpath>//loc:address/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

Which sets the address in the address header.

Edit:
To use xpath on your payload in Java, something like this should do the trick:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(BODY_IN_STRING)));
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String address = xPath.evaluate("//loc:address/text()", document));
```

Comment: Thanks  bhdrkn, Ramin
I am just creating new instance of  org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint and setting payload as dataformat. In my java class method, I get this payload as CXFPayload. I tried unmarshalling the body to my Object but cant get it.  How I can use xpath at my java side ? I don't want to modify my payload.

Comment: Hi Ramin, BODY_IN_STRING will be exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) or
exchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class)?
I see following error when i use exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Prefix loc has not been declared

Comment: Can you try with //address/text() ?

Comment: Ramin, When I use Document document = exchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class);  I see document object content as follows
[#document: null]
any additional changes that will fix this ?